# looking up table-join value from database with cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to access a user's name in a view on cakephp. I'm given a userid and I need to use that to look up their username which is stored in a different table.

The table that I'm retrieving displaying is messages and is as follows

```
id |  title | message | from_user  | to_user | date
```

The users table which contains the username

```
id | username | email | password
```

Anyway how can I look up the username of from_user in the message? I'm still getting used to cake so I don't know how to make a "join" statement without actually writing a query.

Should I send the username from the action in the controller or is it OK to do this from the view?

**edit- I got it to work**

Here is my index function now

```
public function index() {

  $options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'Users',
        'type' => 'inner',
            'fields' => array('user.username'),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Message.from_user = User.id',
            'alias' => 'user_id')
    )
);

$message = $this->Message->find('all', $options);

$this->set('messages', $message);
}
```

I added this to my Message controller and the username now displays, but ONLY for the first message. All of the others it's blank.

```
public $belongsTo = array('User');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to redefine your relationship in Message model :

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Sender' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'from_user'
    ),
    'Recipient' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'to_user'
    )
);
```

Comment: if not getting desired result please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use containable behavior to retrieve that record. What I do is add the behavior to AppModel and set recursive to -1 in AppModel.

Then your `read()` call would turn into

```
public function view($id) {
    $message = $this->Message->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('Message.id' => $id),
        'contain' => array(
            'FromUser' => array('fields' => array('FromUser.username')),
        ),
    ));
    $this->set('message', $message'); // or just $this->set(compact('message'));
}
```

In your view:

```
$message['FromUser']['username'];
```

You may also do a `debug($message);` either in the view or controller to see what exactly is inside the variable and the structure of it.

Assuming you have your relations set up correctly, this should retrieve the FromUser.username field associated with the message record.

More on containable: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html (2.x) and http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable (1.3)

Comment: How do I access the name? Is there some public variable I can now access?

Comment: I'm still slightly confused. Do I put all of that in the appModel? If so, do I make a function named index (that's the name that I use in the controller).

Comment: You would add the behavior to AppModel, the rest of the code in my answer should go inside your `public function view()` Get rid of what you have in their now with your Message->read() and replace it with the code above

Comment: The only part I can't seem to figure out is what to do with the condition that uses $id. Since this will be finding the id's and isn't actually using any variables to do so, what is this $id set to? I'm getting an error because of this. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `$id` in `public function view($id)` gets passed from the url. Ex. `/messages/view/4` would call `MessagesController::view(4)`

Comment: I changed my index function. I found something that I think may be relevant but I'm still getting errors. Mind taking a look?

Comment: Model aliases are singular, so `'Message.from_user = User.id',` if you want to manually do a join. But you should add an `alias` key to your joins array to distinguish which user it is (from or to). So `'alias' => 'FromUser'` and `= FromUser.id` in the conditions